# How to update based on subquery?

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-update

I have two tables:

| Product |
| --- |
| Id |
| Code |
| Value |

| Info |
| --- |
| Id |
| Serial |
| Description |

Now I want to update every column `Code` from table `Product` with the values of `Serial` from table `Info`. My where condition is handy because all my `Product` `code`s are currently `Id` from `Info`.

So this is what I'm attempting:

```
update Product P set
P.Code = (select Serial from Info where id = P.Code);
```

And here I am getting the error: `ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row`.
I feel like I'm missing another where clause but I am not certain where to put it?

Comment: we can't know, your subquery with current condiction return more than one row, you can only do this if subquery return and only return one row. so this only working with one-to-one relation and clearly `info.id` and `product.code` is not one-to-one.

Comment: and what condition can grant you one row only? only you ,who have the data , can know.

Comment: That error means you have multiple records with same id in Info table. try select id, count(1) from info group by id order by 1 desc; to find those id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your subquery returns multiple results (as the error says).
You can limit the updated rows by using, for example, an aggregate function as follows:

```
update Product P set P.Code = (select MAX(Serial) from Info where id = P.Code);
```

Comment: Closest answer to what I need. I wasnt limiting it to one row untill you showed me, thank you!